# Subtracting two IPv6 Addresses Gives Wrong Value

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, ipv6

I have an IP address stored in two 64-bit array. I've noticed least significant bits are in the first byte-little endian.

I'm subtracting two IPv6 addresses which can differ only by 64 bits. So basically, I need to subtract only `addr_end[1]-addr_begin[0]` to get the result.

However the result is not correct.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
struct m128bit {
    union {
        uint8_t  val8[16];
        uint16_t val16[8];
        uint32_t val32[4];
        uint64_t val64[2]; 
    } u;
};
//Overflows 64 bit, too big range (little endian representation)
if (local_begin.u.val64[0] != local_end.u.val64[0]) {
    cout<<"Range is too big!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
else {
    return (local_end.u.val64[1])-(local_begin.u.val64[1]);
}
```

The result is **`0xb`**.
I'm passing in the following IPs:
`2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7335` -`2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7340`

The result should be **5**.

What am I missing? I tried applying `htobe64()` while subtracting the addresses but that didn't work either (I get `0xb`, instead of `0xb00000000000000`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not print out what you're trying to subtract?  At the very least it would help you to see what values you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hex the number of elements between `7335` to `7340` is as follows.

**`7335`**`,7336,7337,7338,7339,733a,733b,733c,733d,733e,733f,`**`7340`**

So when you subtract `7335` from `7340` you will get `11` in base 10 i.e. `0xb` in `hex` and thats what you are getting `0xb` and is expected.

Answer (score 1):

> The result should be 5.

Nope.  The numbers in those IPv6 addresses are all in hex.

0x7340 - 0x7335 is 0xb

In base 10

29504 - 29493 is 11.